# Journey Builder Engagement split

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

How Engagement split work?

If I select data extension into journey builder and send an email after that using engagement split with "Click" if yes then update the record with Salesforce data and if no then send a reminder email to the subscriber.

What does the Click mean? Just open the email or click on any link into the email? 
Thanks !!!

Answer (score 2):

Engagement split has the option to select a previously sent email in the journey if it had been opened, clicked, bounced etc.

If you have multiple links in an email and you want to make a decision based on one of those you can assign an alias to the link like

```
<a href="http://google.com" alias="Google">go to google</a>
```

This will allow you to select a click on a specific link, otherwise you can choose any click.

Once your journey is split you can then use Salesforce update object activities or send another email on the branches that are applicable.